# Career Advice - Software engineer at 15 years old

Tags: software-industry, internship

I'm currently in a bit of a wiggle; I am currently employed by the hour at a consulting firm with 6~ other devs employed.

Although the company is somewhat successful I am not getting quite the amount of clients I'd like;

1 small client project~ /month

And the salary might be seen as "ok" as a teenager, but looking at the avg Swedish SF it does not come close, and that's expected when paid by the hour I guess, but I still feel like it's an underpayment.
What I am trying to do is get an intern position at a larger company, larger meaning a better reference on a resume & hopefully a bit better paid.

But all intern positions I've seen require a bachelor degree OR currently graduating with a bachelor degree; and as stated above, I am only 15 and only in ninth grade (Nordic school years) so it is not quite possible.

To be honest, I'd work for free for a good reference/contacts.

What would you guys suggest I do at this point? I don't wanna wait another 4-6 years to get a junior job, and school is really no problem. I am currently available 40-60 hours per week for work. I guess my goal is to build up some sort of network of references for the future.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks! :)

Comment: It might be useful to explore apprenticeship programs. While you're doing very well learning in your own, these companies help young learners bypass the collegiate/time requirements and can be expected to help navigate labor laws. They also have lots of company contacts for places who are looking for young developers to help grow the market.

Comment: I would look into contributing to open source projects if I were you

Comment: I would expect it rare to find companies willing to hire a junior developer unable to work typical 9-5 working patterns.   While senior engineers often have the experience to work productively out-of-hours, it's tough for a junior who would need a lot of mentoring and closer real-time collaboration with others.   Maybe you can devote many hours per week, but most of those hours are likely evenings and weekends when everyone else who works for the company would be enjoying their own free time.

Comment: @BenCottrell Yeah that's a good point, but in my case, I set my own hours for studies - amazing right?

Comment: As for @JoeStrazzere - Yeah that's true, I got lucky, but I'm just looking to expand my knowledge & experience :)

Comment: Getting an internship will be hard if you have to go to school at the same time. Internships are instead of school, so usually during summer vacation. The point of internships is also as a veto system for future employees. At 15 years old people might think you are too young for a full time employment in the next few years and even consider that your priorities should focus on school (and they will be right). So you won't qualify for most internships. But it doesn't hurt to ask :)....

Comment: ... You have quite some experience so far. If I were in a similar position I would keep going at my current role and at the same time spend some time to polish my "HR talk skills" and learn to write good personalized internship cover letters to highlight my experience and willingness to work for specific companies and target a summer internship with one of them. The worse that can happen is they say no. Do consult with your parents or custodian before though, just so you avoid being taken advantage of.

Comment: @Bogdan Yeah studies will always be at the top right now. But I am a quick learner, so studies have never been a real challenge.
What exactly do you mean by `HR talk skills`?

Comment: If I could go back in time and give myself some advice, I would have been not to work so much when I was young. I missed a lot of parties, and going out, in order to work. I'm not saying you shouldn't work. Just you may want to to think about if you will have enough time to have fun if you're juggling work and studying. (For some people I understand this is just a reality).

Comment: @Collbrothers: I mean to learn how to write for non technical people, in this case HR as the main audience. That means to improve your communication skills, to write a convincing cover letter, something that attracts attention and highlights your achievements and your attitude towards work (and especially working for them :)), formatting the cover letter to look good, etc. HR is used to see certain things in the applications. You have to make sure you tick those boxes or HR will throw your cover letter in the bin.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Yeah I see that, but I'm really not the social type lmao, but yes; I see how I might miss some things in life

Comment: @Bogdan Oh yeah, that seems like a good thing to know, I'll do my research! Thanks! :)

Comment: "To be honest, I'd work for free for a good reference/contacts." - Wait...What?  You are currently working.  Why don't you get references and contacts from the company that choose to hire you? On a personal note, how on earth as a teenager are you available to work 60 hours per week? Most professional software engineers don't even work 60 hours per week.

Comment: If you work for free to get reputation, you will get a reputation as the guy who works for free. You do not want that, you want to be recommended by and to people who value your work enough to pay for it.

Comment: Is it an option for you to graduate and enter college early?

Comment: OP, if you're a "genius" (I think so), I believe that maths/physics are easy for you. I would recommend you to search for a field that you love and go for a Phd. You're young and I understand that you may want to gain some money but this is a short term goal. Software Engineer at 15, that sound like the past of a great Computer Science Doctor to me. Science study can be really amusing. The choice is up to you, do what you love OP.

Comment: @PowerCat Yeah no I wouldn't qualify myself as a genius, I'm a fast learning nerd lmao. But yes, I am currently enrolling in an astrophysics course & math included ofc. And including Daniel's topic too; I'm currently trying to find a way _around_ the current laws of Swedish education, but it does not look good...

Comment: You could try to join other country ? I'm pretty sure some country would be happy to have you, there is always a way to make thing happen ! Good luck OP

Comment: @PowerCat What do you mean? Get citizenship in another country? If so I can't figure a _good_ country to _join_, the US requires one to be 18+ when filing for citizenship so...

Comment: Not necessary getting the citizenship but I guess that contacting different university explaining your plan and sending them your grades etc .. Could give you the opportunity to talk with them about your potential, they could help you to join as a foreigner student and accelerate thing if they are interested (they will if you're already a excellent Phd candidate !). Maybe, you could do "official examen" for university/college entrance, here in France, it would be "Bac" (Baccalauréat) before joining university. If you got it, you are legaly allowed to join university, no matter your age.

Comment: That makes more sense! Now I’ll just have to do my lil research on some good uni's. And I did reach out to the “Harvard” of Sweden universities to see if they have experienced this before and if they might put me in. But I’ll try to find some good candidates for universities. Thanks Powercat! :)

Answer (score 17):

Speaking as someone who is more than twice  your age: You are  15 years old.  You will have many, many years of your life to work  and make money.  While you're young, be young.  Spend your time hanging out with your friends, playing video games (or whatever it is you like to do), surfing Reddit, or so on.  Don't spend 40-60 hours per week coding for some company; you'll regret it later in life.

As  a side note, are you in school?  If you have 60 hours per week to code, plus roughly 40 hours per week in school, that's a lot of hours.  You'll definitely burn yourself out if you  do 8 hours of school and then another 8 hours of work per day.  You're too young to burn yourself out.  Concentrate on school, study hard, graduate well, go to a good college, get a solid degree in CS or SE or some related field, and then you'll certainly have a great career.

For now, you're still young, so be young and enjoy being  young.  You will have lots of years to work and make money, don't sweat it while you're young.  If you want to spend some time doing some side work for pocket money, then by all means go ahead  and do that (and it sounds like you are), but don't try to get a full-time  job at the age of 15.  It's not worth it, you'll have plenty of years to do this  in the future, but now is not the time.

Comment: I am not sure how the author is even available to work 60 hours a week.  That is 12 hours a day (assuming a Monday through Friday) schedule.  Most professionals don't even work 60 hours a week.

Comment: @Donald If you have no life, you can schedule an 8/8/8 day where you school for 8 hours, work 8 hours, and sleep 8 hours, so that gets you 40, then you  add 10 hours per day on weekends (because you don't have school so you can work all day),  and that gets you to 60.  Not that this is in any way a healthy lifestyle and I certainly don't advise or condone it, but it is possible,  if someone would like to have no life.

Comment: -1 I'm actually not in favor of telling ambitious young people to chill out and fritter their time away. There are many people who successfully go to college at that age. If such opportunities were available, it's equally possible to have regrets in the other direction.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins If OP was working instead of going to school, I would understand that (I would disagree with it; school is important, but at least I would understand.  OP is taking their free time and using it to work.  Work-life balance is important, and if OP is going to school (which is basically "work" for a young person) and then in their free time they are doing more work, that's not healthy.  Spending time developing hobbies, relationships (friends and otherwise), and having life experiences, is not "fritter[ing] their time away", it's an important part of growing up.

Comment: @Ertai87: You're extrapolating your experiences as a universal. To many (e.g.: me), our hobbies, relationships, and experiences at age 15 have pretty much zero relevance to our later life arc.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins It's actually a well-known and well-documented fact in child psychology that children need to be children, in order to be functional adults when they grow up.  Hence why we view things such as child labour in despotic countries as abhorrent, and why organizations such as UNICEF are devoted to ending such practices.  The specifics of which hobbies, or which friends you make, are less important, but learning general skills such as socialization are very important in childhood development.

Comment: @Ertai87: 15 is not really "childhood", that's spurious.

Comment: @Ertai87 Yeah you make a good point, but as Daniel states, I wouldn't say I am in "childhood" per se.  I've had my share of hobbies & friends but my syndromes aren't really a helping hand in this category. So while I have my _non-work_ or _non-tech_ hobbies & friends I feel like I actually enjoy "overworking". I'm fully aware it sounds nuts, but right now I just wanna see what doors are open for someone like me in the world of tech.

Comment: @Collbrothers It doesn't sound nuts, but the thing about a job is that when it's not a job, it's fun, but once it's a job, it becomes a responsibility, and responsibilities are always less fun.  Think about it this way: You have the freedom now to make the choice if you want to work or hang out with friends.  You are choosing to work.  When you have a job, you no longer have the other choice, to hang out with friends instead of work; you have to work (or quit your job).  When you're on the other side of the fence and don't have the choice, you will find yourself wishing you did.

Answer (score 5):

Wow, at 15, you are doing very well.

The problem you have is that the laws want to protect you from unscrupulous people who have harmed young people. The larger the company, the more they have to follow the laws and I doubt they would take you on as an intern. I have read about teenagers who got around these laws by building their own companies. You would need help from your parents and other adults who know the laws. You may need them to "counter sign" legal documents and contracts with clients. But building your own company is doable. Lycka till.

Edit: This answer is based on US laws rather than Swedish law.

Comment: "Lycka till" surprised me lmao. Well as I made sure before I signed the contract with my current company. Sweden allows 2006 (as I am) to work with jobs that do not put me in any chance of physical harm, and more responsibilities & more advanced responsibilities :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to get a Job and a company to employ you, as a software engineer you can easily start working on your portfolio.

Honestly it is more impressive if you can show for 3 successfull software projects, that might even made you money at age 15 than saying "oh I have been an intern at big Company A". Because usually intern positions dont get important projects and in my experience underaged interns usually get nothing at all other than getting coffee, watching others, sweeping floors and maybe working on some practice stuff.

Also remember that indeed you are very young. I am twice your age and understand your urgency, I was the same. But as someone said burn out is real. I have been working since I was 16 because I wanted it so much, burned out and since last year I didnt have a real job because of the burn out I spent years in part time jobs and my degree suffered severely. I could have been an A student but because I didnt want to stop working and kept doing more and more everything went really bad.
I honestly can be glad that someone wanted to employ me at all. Dont make the same mistake young lad. If you have free time to projects for yourself that are fun. You can always show those projects later on to get an interview.
I would recommend to finish your degree first though and do it well. If you force an internship now and maybe even dont get a degree because someone offers you to work right now for them, it will bite you back later, guarantueed.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to finding some sort of employment at your age would be to refer to friends of your parents or other adults that are close to you (teachers at school for example). They might give you a strong recommendation or introduce you to someone who might be able to get you a position. I am pretty sure that they will find some sort of connection and you will at least get a shot.

But keep in mind what Ertai87 said in his answer. You are full of energy and because of this it is very easy to forget yourself in work and burn yourself out. Responsibilities accumulate, tread carefully.

Göra det lagom som man säger i Sverige!